All I know is that is/was what they say/said
I think I have a dumb question ... I was just wondering if any of the following sentence are grammatically correct and if some are interchangeable:

"All I know is that is what they said" vs.

"All I know is that is what they say" vs.

"All I know is that was what they said" vs

"All I know is that was what they say" (I think this one is incorrect)


Thank you for your help in advance !

This is the same thing in French. Is that your native language? The they said. they say bit.

Hello ~ No ... Thank you for the comment !

First, a note on punctuation.
If you want that specific sentence structure, I would add a comma:

All I know is, that is what they said.

I'm reading your sentence like this: I know only one thing. That [some statement referred to previously] is what they said. There's a similar structure, which reads All I know is that they said [something]. The issue here is the word that, which can refer backwards to what I know, or forwards to what they said.
As currently written, that can only refer forward to what they said. But the mixture of similar words makes it potentially confusing. You have to stop and think. The comma helps to separate the clauses and makes it easier to read. Or you could change the whole structure:

I only know one thing. That is what they said.

Second, a note on tenses
My advice is always: don't ask if the tenses are correct. Ask if they mean what you want them to mean. In other words, choose the tense that communicates what you want to say. All of your examples could be correct in the right context, even the one you weren't sure about.

[All I know is] that is what they said (= "They said something in the past, and I know about it now.")

[All I know is] that is what they say. (="They are saying something now, and I know about it now.")

[All I know is] that was what they said. (= "They said something in the past, and although I know about it now, I want to emphasise the fact that they said it back then. That was what they said.)

[All I know is] that was what they say. (This sentence is less likely, but possible. It could mean "That is what they said then, and they are still saying it now." What they said is a continuing declaration that they are holding to.)


The main point of all this is, work out first what you want to say, then find the tenses that do the job for you.

Thank you all so very much for your detailed explanations !

In 1 and 3, the saying was done in the past.  In 2, the saying is ongoing.
In 3,  that was what they said has its linking verb backshifted to match the past event.  This is fine.
In 1, there is no backshift.  This is possible if they have not made any statements to override their earlier one.
In 2, they are still saying that.  It is an ongoing topic, and this is their current view.
4 is incorrect.
